# SQL Query to fetch multiple record which is NULL and insert into target table

Tags: oracle, validation

To fetch specified columns where there is a null and then insert into the target table table. I have used case expression but in this the issue is if it gets first specified column as NULL then it doesnt checks another column and it goes to next row
so if in one row I have 3 columns out of 7 specified columns as NULL then case will only fetch the first one but I want to fetch all specified columns and insert into target table in different rows for each column with hard coded values
I cannot use loop, cursor for performance isssue as there are more than 10 million records.
By SQL Query
Need to just fetch L_ID, Telephone and rec_id from source table.

```
INSERT INTO TARGET table(DOMAIN, FALLOUT_ID, SEVERITY, BUSINESS_RULE, CHECKED_TABLE, CHECKED_COLUMN, FALLOUT_TYPE, L_ID, TELEPHONE, ADDITIONAL_CONDITION, REC_ID)
SELECT
'AT' AS DOMAIN,
CASE 
WHEN DOMS NULL THEN 'VLD_DOMS' 
WHEN ROMS NULL THEN 'VLD_ROMS'
WHEN COMS IS NULL THEN 'VLD_COMS'
END AS FALLOUT_ID,
'MAJOR' AS SEVERITY,
CASE
WHEN DOMS IS NULL THEN 'DOMS should be not null'
WHEN ROMS IS NULL THEN 'ROMS should be not null'
WHEN COMS IS NULL THEN 'COMS should be not null'
END AS BUSINESS_RULE,
'Source_table' AS CHECKED_TABLE,
CASE
WHEN DOMS IS NULL THEN 'DOMS'
WHEN ROMS IS NULL THEN 'ROMS'
WHEN COMS IS NULL THEN 'COMS'
END AS CHECKED_COLUMN,
'NNL' AS FALLOUT_TYPE,
L_ID,
TELEPHONE,
CASE
WHEN DOMS IS NULL THEN 'DOMS should contain value'
WHEN ROMS IS NULL THEN 'ROMS should contain date'
WHEN COMS IS NULL THEN 'COMS should be not null'
END AS ADDITIONAL_CONDITION,
REC_ID
FROM source table
WHERE DOMS IS NULL
OR ROMS IS NULL
OR COMS IS NULL;
```

I tried Case expression but it is checking one column and if its true then not checking other columns and directly going to next row.

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags (mysql and oracle). Please add the one back that you actually use.

Answer (score 0):

## Queries

You could do it with three inserts:

### 1

```
INSERT INTO TARGET table(DOMAIN, FALLOUT_ID, SEVERITY, BUSINESS_RULE, CHECKED_TABLE, CHECKED_COLUMN, FALLOUT_TYPE, L_ID, TELEPHONE, ADDITIONAL_CONDITION, REC_ID)
SELECT
'AT' AS DOMAIN,
'VLD_DOMS' AS FALLOUT_ID,
'MAJOR' AS SEVERITY,
'DOMS should be not null' AS BUSINESS_RULE,
'Source_table' AS CHECKED_TABLE,
'DOMS' AS CHECKED_COLUMN,
'NNL' AS FALLOUT_TYPE,
L_ID,
TELEPHONE,
'DOMS should contain value' AS ADDITIONAL_CONDITION,
REC_ID
FROM source table
WHERE DOMS IS NULL;
```

### 2

```
INSERT INTO TARGET table(DOMAIN, FALLOUT_ID, SEVERITY, BUSINESS_RULE, CHECKED_TABLE, CHECKED_COLUMN, FALLOUT_TYPE, L_ID, TELEPHONE, ADDITIONAL_CONDITION, REC_ID)
SELECT
'AT' AS DOMAIN,
'VLD_ROMS' AS FALLOUT_ID,
'MAJOR' AS SEVERITY,
'ROMS should be not null' AS BUSINESS_RULE,
'Source_table' AS CHECKED_TABLE,
'ROMS' AS CHECKED_COLUMN,
'NNL' AS FALLOUT_TYPE,
L_ID,
TELEPHONE,
'ROMS should contain date' END AS ADDITIONAL_CONDITION,
REC_ID
FROM source table
WHERE ROMS IS NULL;
```

### 3

```
INSERT INTO TARGET table(DOMAIN, FALLOUT_ID, SEVERITY, BUSINESS_RULE, CHECKED_TABLE, CHECKED_COLUMN, FALLOUT_TYPE, L_ID, TELEPHONE, ADDITIONAL_CONDITION, REC_ID)
SELECT
'AT' AS DOMAIN,
'VLD_COMS' AS FALLOUT_ID,
'MAJOR' AS SEVERITY,
'COMS should be not null' AS BUSINESS_RULE,
'Source_table' AS CHECKED_TABLE,
'COMS' AS CHECKED_COLUMN,
'NNL' AS FALLOUT_TYPE,
L_ID,
TELEPHONE,
'COMS should be not null' AS ADDITIONAL_CONDITION,
REC_ID
FROM source table
WHERE COMS IS NULL;
```

Untested, if there are typos, please fix them.

## Performance

I understand that you have performance issues to cope with. In order to improve performance, you will need to index your fields of `DOMS`, `ROMS` and `COMS` so the query will not have to check for each and every record in your `source` table and check them for being `null`, but, instead it will instantly know where they are.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the insertion of multiple records based on each `NULL` column in a single row, you can use a combination of `UNION ALL` with individual SELECT statements for each column that could be `NULL`. This way, you will create a separate row in the target table for each `NULL` column in the source table.

Here's an example of how you can modify your query to insert a row for each `NULL` column:

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE (
    DOMAIN, FALLOUT_ID, SEVERITY, BUSINESS_RULE, CHECKED_TABLE, 
    CHECKED_COLUMN, FALLOUT_TYPE, L_ID, TELEPHONE, ADDITIONAL_CONDITION, REC_ID
)
SELECT 'AT' AS DOMAIN, 'VLD_DOMS' AS FALLOUT_ID, 'MAJOR' AS SEVERITY,
    'DOMS should be not null' AS BUSINESS_RULE, 'source_table' AS CHECKED_TABLE,
    'DOMS' AS CHECKED_COLUMN, 'NNL' AS FALLOUT_TYPE, L_ID, TELEPHONE,
    'DOMS should contain value' AS ADDITIONAL_CONDITION, REC_ID
FROM source_table
WHERE DOMS IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 'AT' AS DOMAIN, 'VLD_ROMS' AS FALLOUT_ID, 'MAJOR' AS SEVERITY,
    'ROMS should be not null' AS BUSINESS_RULE, 'source_table' AS CHECKED_TABLE,
    'ROMS' AS CHECKED_COLUMN, 'NNL' AS FALLOUT_TYPE, L_ID, TELEPHONE,
    'ROMS should contain date' AS ADDITIONAL_CONDITION, REC_ID
FROM source_table
WHERE ROMS IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 'AT' AS DOMAIN, 'VLD_COMS' AS FALLOUT_ID, 'MAJOR' AS SEVERITY,
    'COMS should be not null' AS BUSINESS_RULE, 'source_table' AS CHECKED_TABLE,
    'COMS' AS CHECKED_COLUMN, 'NNL' AS FALLOUT_TYPE, L_ID, TELEPHONE,
    'COMS should be not null' AS ADDITIONAL_CONDITION, REC_ID
FROM source_table
WHERE COMS IS NULL;
```

This method uses `UNION ALL` to combine the results of three separate SELECT statements, each one checking for NULL in one of the columns (DOMS, ROMS, COMS). If a row in source_table has multiple `NULL` columns, it will result in multiple rows in the target table, one for each `NULL` column.

Please note that `UNION ALL` does not remove duplicate rows between the select statements, which is what we want in this case because a single row in the source table could potentially lead to multiple rows in the target table if multiple columns are `NULL`.

It's important to ensure that the performance of the `UNION ALL` operation is acceptable with your dataset size. Since you mentioned having over 10 million records, make sure that your database is properly indexed, especially on the columns being checked for `NULL` values. This will help the database engine to efficiently process the query.

Comment: for performance its better to not use select many times so is there any other way where it is selecting the source table only once?